# How to detect if night mode is activated?

Tags: android-studio

I need to know if night mode is activated, with a boolean or int, I found a boolean that detects but it only works from andorid R isnightmodeactive () and I can't find another way to know if night mode is activated or not, any idea

I did this test but I continue as before it does not throw anything, I do not know how to know what mode my device is in, night or day

```
    public double isDark(int a) {
    return a;
     }  

 public void nightmode(){

            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
            if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES){
                isDark(1);
            }else if(AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO){
                isDark(2);
            }
```

}

Comment: Android Studio is a text editor, not a programming language. Are you using Java or Kotlin or something else?

Comment: Im programming  in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google it or search on developer.android.com. I found a [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787035/is-there-an-api-to-detect-which-theme-the-os-is-using-dark-or-light-or-other/56515949#56515949). 
Here is the kotlin code from that question

```
fun Context.isDarkThemeOn(): Boolean{
    return resources.configuration.uiMode and 
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

Comment: How would that be in java

Comment: @jose moya, see this article -> https://blog.mindorks.com/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file

Comment: I already did it but nothing happens, it does not give me an int or boolean that tells me if the phone is activated or in night mode

Comment: It should return true or false or UI mode as a string or any other type. It **should** return something.

Comment: Download fernflower.jar from https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jboss.windup.decompiler/decompiler-fernflower/3.0.0.Final/source-code

Comment: You can see what I tried, I just edited my original post I still don't get any data

Comment: so, try this code:
`public boolean Context.isDarkThemeOn(){
      return Configuration. Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
}`

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert at android but an expert @ java. I have some programming experience. So @josemoya, see these StackOverflow questions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170028/android-how-to-detect-if-night-mode-is-on-when-using-appcompatdelegate-mode-ni || 
https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/d1rgwl/detecting_android_q_dark_mode/