# How to implement android follow system night/dark mode?

Tags: java, android, android-theme, android-dark-theme, android-night-mode

I have set *Light* and *Dark* mode in my app and its working.

But I also want to add an option to let the app follow the mode set by the system. So user can choose among three options.

I tried to do it, but was unsuccessful. I want to add Radio Buttons to switch to Light, Dark, Follow System Mode.

`Here's what I have tried`

```
public class setting extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Switch darkMode;
    Button autoButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.darktheme);
        }
        else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setTitleTextAppearance(this, R.style.Font);

        darkMode = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.darkModeSwitch);
        autoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.autoButton);

        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            darkMode.setChecked(true);
        }

        darkMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    getDelegate().applyDayNight();
                    recreate();
                    //restartApp();
                }
                else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    recreate();
                    // restartApp();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Here you find anwser to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787035/is-there-an-api-to-detect-which-theme-the-os-is-using-dark-or-light-or-other

Comment: I want to add an option to 'follow the system wide theme' which was officially introduced in android 10 and if set could change to light/dark mode, depending on whichever is set in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s an option that does this: `AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
```

Comment: Thanks
I got this working but i was not able the change color of status and navigation bar
for example on light/day theme white status and navigation bar
and on dark/night theme black status and navigation bar

Comment: You'll have to restructure your themes to do this. See https://ataulm.com/2020/04/30/refactoring-themes-with-style.html, then GitHub.com/ataulm/android for an example