# How my app can acknowledge the system transition theme (dark -> light / light -> dark) on android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

My app should do something every time the system theme changes status.

I'm using android studio, maybe Kotlin or Java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787035/is-there-an-api-to-detect-which-theme-the-os-is-using-dark-or-light-or-other

Comment: Thanks, since android lately (april 2020 I guess) added support for auto switch theme do you know how the system get the time for the theme switch?

Comment: See "Be notified of a change in the theme" in linked duplicate

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Declare darkmode color in another night color file

Answer (score 0):

> My app should do something every time the system theme changes status

Are you talking about [dark theme](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme)?

If so, the trick is to use *theme attributes* instead of specific colors in your layouts and then use a theme that supports dark mode, see above link for more information.

Comment: When the system theme changes (dark mode activate/deactivate) the app should do something, so I believe to have the app asleep while the switch does not happen and when it does, the app awake and does what it has to do then goes back asleep, waiting for the next change

Comment: Changing to dark theme is a configuration change. Android will recreate all views automatically for you right away, see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#ondestroy