# Android - Detect if the user's OS theme is dark or light?

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-dark-theme, android-darkmode

I need to know if user has enabled dark theme in the OS level so that I can enable dark theme in my app automatically.(not force dark mode)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an API to detect which theme the OS is using - dark or light (or other)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55787035/is-there-an-api-to-detect-which-theme-the-os-is-using-dark-or-light-or-other)

Comment: Just so you know, Android can do this automatically if your app's theme extends one of the `MaterialComponents.DayNight` themes. But check the link above if you want to do it manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To detect if the system is in dark theme. Helpful.

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
       //process
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // process
        break; 
}
```

Comment: are you calling `getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode` off of the activity context? or application context?

Comment: Activity, the Application context does not contain theme information.